# convert nested for loop logic using stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, time-complexity, big-o

I have a set of code which I want to perform using stream I have done using for loop but unable to do it using stream or other better approach please advice

```
for (Student student : students) {
        List<Laptop> filteredLaptop = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Laptop laptop: student.getLaptopList()) {
            if(laptop.getColour().endsWith("RED")){
                filteredLaptop.add(laptop);
            }
        }
        student.setLaptopList(filteredLaptop);
 }
```

How can i reduce the complexity of code or how can perform same operation using Stream

Comment: *"How can i reduce the complexity of code?"* You can't. --- *"How can perform same operation using Stream?"* Why would you want to? There's nothing wrong with this code. Converting it to stream will not improve the code, and will actually make it run slower.

Comment: complexity is n2 is there any way to to improve the complexity @Andreas

Comment: Why do you believe that complexity is _O(n^2)_? What is your `n`? --- Depending on your variables, complexity is either _O(n)_ where `n` is the total number of laptops, or it is _O(n*m)_ where `n` is the number of students and `m` is the *average* number of laptops per student.

Comment: ... and you cannot reduce this further below from `O(n*m)` unless there is something concrete you are trying to achieve other than visiting all laptops of each students to identify if they are a match or not. With respect to the code, you can perform a `removeIf` over the student's laptop list(those not matching your criteria) to update it in place.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I think it's better to rename laptopsList)

```
students.forEach(student -> 
  student.setLaptops(
    student.getLaptops().stream()
      .filter(laptop -> laptop.getColour().endsWith("RED"))
      .collect(toList())
    )
 );
```